# How to continue video capture when app goes background then comes in foreground?

Tags: ios, video

I want to continue video capture if application become active from inactive state.

Complete scenario

1.Capture video of 5 sec
2.App goes to background.
3.Now app comes in foreground and in this condition I want to continue video capture with previous video which I have captured.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@"someSelector" name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil]` to pause your recording and then you can use `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@"someOtherSelector" name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil]` to resume your video recording.
someSelector and someOtherSelector are the methods that will be implemented by you according to your requirement.